# Add thottle middleware to seperate routes with seperate counting tries

Tags: laravel, throttling, rate-limiting

I have 2 routes and i want to limit user to access them just 5 time per hour. I'm using throttle middleware like below:

```
Route::middleware('throttle:5,60')->group(function () {
    Route::get('test1' , function (){
        return 'test1';
    });
});

Route::middleware('throttle:5,60')->group(function () {
    Route::get('test2' , function (){
        return 'test2';
    });
});
```

the problem is if an user visits route test1 5 times, after that both routes test1 and test2 returns TooManyAttempts error. i want the user be able to visit each route 5 time per hour seperately. if user visits test1 5 times then he can visit test2 5 times.

can it be done in throttle middleware?

Comment: Does this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28339) has anything to do with it? This is not my area of expertise, just a pointer.

Comment: @mat-j thank you. looks like this is an issue they working on it.